# Subquery in MySQL with joined tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a subquery but am failing miserably at it.  My query fails with this error...

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What I want is to find all accounts where the `schickUpdatedDate` field has a date value within the last 40 days and no not have either 'Initial Waranty' or 'None' as values in the support_c field.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM accounts 
LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c 
WHERE schickUpdatedDate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 40 DAY AND NOW()IN
  (SELECT * FROM accounts_cstm WHERE support_c != 'Initial Waranty' OR support_c != 'None')
ORDER BY schickUpdatedDate ASC
```

All of the fields above are in the accounts_ctsm table, the accounts table if joined for another purpose other than this.

Comment: 'SELECT *' - generates the error you just need a date from accounts_cstm (ie Operand should contain 1 column(s))

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit my question.  It was all accounts with a schickUpdatedDate value in the last 40 days that do not have the other values I mentioned.

Comment: I can't see that that new information adds anything of import.

Comment: the first comment said I just need a date from accounts_cctm.  I took this that they thought I was looking for one record but I'm looking for all that match the criteria.

Comment: The `in` should only have one column to return as the CSV. You also don't be comparing that to anything. e.g. `NOW() and somecolumn IN
  (SELECT another column FROM accounts_cstm`

Comment: do you know what operand I should be using please and what the query should look like?  I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to show the joined output filtered by 3 criteria. I don't think you need a subquery for it then.

Does this work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c 
WHERE schickUpdatedDate >= (curdate() - interval 40 day)
and support_c <> 'Initial Waranty' 
and support_c <> 'None'
ORDER BY schickUpdatedDate ASC;
```

Comment: More likely it should just be `AND support_c NOT IN ('Initial Warranty', 'None')`

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly.  I've been away from mysql for a while and I think I was over thinking it